# parse log4net logs and forward to Logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, logstash-grok

> 2018-05-07 11:38:56,748 [15] ERROR Library.Logger.Log4NetLogger
>   [(null)] - {"Component":"Service","Message":"Exception in
>   Authorization.Exception:No Roles were found for the login Id:
>   Domain\user0
>   ","Exception":{"ClassName":"System.Exception","Message":"No Roles were
>   found for the login Id:
>   Domain\User0","Data":{},"InnerException":null,"HelpURL":null,"StackTraceString":"
>   at Authorization.GetRoles(String loginId) in AuthorizationBll.cs:line
>   146\r\n at AuthorizationBll.CheckAuthorization(String loginId, String
>   operationName) in \Services\AuthorizationBll.cs:line
>   61","RemoteStackTraceString":null,"RemoteStackIndex":0,"ExceptionMethod":"8\nGetRoles\nServices.BusinessLogic,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null\nAuthorizationBll\nSystem.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]
>   GetRoles(System.String)","HResult":-2146233088,"Source":"Services.BusinessLogic","WatsonBuckets":null},"ErrorLevel":1,"ErrorLevelType":"Error","CurrentDateTime":"2018-05-07T11:38:56.6918708+05:30","ManagedThreadId":15,"AdditonalData":null,"Context":null}

I have this logs , I want to extract 4 things from text and put to elastic search. I'm using the following grok

> %{GREEDYDATA:message}
>
> 1. Component Name 2. Message 3 : Exception 4 : stack trace.

How can this be done ?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: So when i use %{GREEDYDATA:message} i get the entire message , post that i have tried to find the querystring with help of %{QS} but that gives arbitary results back.   I want to understand is there a way i can use regex post using %{GREEDYDATA:message} so that i can match the pattern to find the results i want